# Project Guideline/ Suggestions: Arduino Mega-Raspberry Pi Combo for HD Video Streaming with Stamping

Tags: sd-card, arduino, streaming-video

I hope all is well. I'm new to the Raspberry Pi arena, and would love some feedback on the feasibility of this project:

I have an Arduino Mega that's logging data (in addition to other stuff which is I believe is not relevant here). I want a raspberry pi setup where the pi can live stream HD videos out of 5 cameras simultaneously while "stamping" each stream (on the corner of the video screen, for example), with some of the data that the Mega is logging.

At the end of the "day" (or the end of the experiment), I want the pi to access data on an SD card "through" the Mega, and upload the files onto a server.

Is this setup feasible? If not, what can I change? If so, do you have any suggestions for pi models and camera models that I can start with?

Thank you again, and please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: Adding more information would be helpful for experts here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there any particular info you'd like me to provide?

Comment: The cameras are going to be attached to the RPi? Of course, this setup is feasible.

Comment: This question may be overly broad and border on opinion-based in some parts. Please try focusing on a single aspect of your project and ask for help with that. For example, asking how to transfer data between a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino Mega may get you an answer (I would suggest UART but your comment about the SD card threw me off).

Comment: Got it; I'll narrow it down ASAP.